# Why are my bash scripts refusing to run until I type 'exit' ever since I used 'script /dev/null'?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I am working on a cluster, the 'home' machine of which runs Linux version 2.6.38.4 on Debian 4.3.2-1.1. Other machines on the cluster run more recent versions of Linux (3.x.x.x) but on differing flavours (some Redhat, some Debian etc).

As usual, I transferred to chos 8 on one of these machines and set a script running in a screen, but the server began denying that there were any sockets available when I went to reattach it. I followed advice I found online and typed ‘script /dev/null’ in order to retrieve my screens, but it keeps happening. Also, when I start a new screen now, the command prompt is preceded by ‘(base)’.

Now, if I try to run a bash script on anything other than the home machine, the scripts won't run until I follow the command with 'exit', as follows:

```
bash ~/DAPHNIA/Scripts/compare_BUSCO_depths.sh 2 21 3 3 2-WGS_Clone_21_CGCTATGT-GTGTCGGA_L001;

exit;
```

The contents of the script don't seem to matter - this irritating quirk now happens regardless of the script being run.

Does anybody have any idea a) what has caused this, and b) how I can fix it, please?

Comment: Sounds like you're creating a new shell with your first line which is why the scripts appear to be unresponsive. Edit: try using bash -c 'stuff to run in here' or not using the bash command at all to run that script

Comment: `script` is not a command to the current shell; it's an external command that starts a *new* shell, and `script` does not complete until that shell exits. Using `script /dev/null` doesn't sound particularly useful, though. You might want to use a program like `tmux` for persisting a shell session beyond your current connection.

Comment: Thanks very much to both of you for your help and the information. Unfortunately, the problem persists. I tried making one of the scripts executable and running it without the 'bash' command, but it still required me typing 'exit' to run. I also tried removing the shebang at the start of the file but no luck there either. 

Could I have broken something important with the commands I described? I don't see how...

@chepner - tmux looks useful (https://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-tmux/ for anyone looking for an overview) but is this preferable to just using 'screen'?

Comment: @IanW That's primarily a matter of opinion. `tmux` is newer (and so learned from and improved on `screen`'s design) and easier to script, `screen` can do some things (e.g., connect directly to a serial device) that `tmux` can't, but both ultimately serve the same purpose: provide programs with a terminal that doesn't depend on you being continuously logged in. If you are new to either, I would suggest using `tmux`.

Comment: Ah, gotcha - thanks, I'll have a play around with tmux :)

Also, just a few clarifiers for anyone looking at this question: The scripts that have been failing to run without me typing 'exit' include the line 'chos 8', just in case I hadn't already moved there. This was what needed exiting before the scripts would run. As for the '(base)' mystery - I'd recently installed conda and it had inserted itself into my .bashrc file, causing the issue. A lot of red herrings here but it's looking better now, although I rue the day I installed conda!